# Framework for creating iPhone chat application

Tags: iphone, frameworks, chat

I want to create chat application in iPhone. Are there any framework(s) which support the same? Do I have to use a third party tool for creating it? If yes, which one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can write it directly you can create from Objective-C. In [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ioschat/index.html) nearly everything is explained.

But if you want to create in JavaScript and HTML, there is a application called Appcelerator Titanium that you can use to develop the application. You can [look here](http://boldr.net/iphone-app-with-titanium-mobile) to see a chat example with Titanium. Titanium converts your code to Objective-C at the end.

Comment: Thanks Cenk for your efforts.

Comment: it doesn't matter i hope you find the solution